# AVAssetExportSession export mp3 while keeping metadata

Tags: macos, mp3, avfoundation, id3, avmetadataitem

How do I export a mp3 using `AVAssetExportSession` while keeping the id3 tags?  Is it possible to edit the id3 tags before exporting them?

This code does write the `AVAsset` (myMp3Asset) to file but the there are no id3 tag in the resulting mp3.

```
// myMp3Asset is an AVAsset
AVAssetExportSession *exportS = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                 initWithAsset:myMp3Asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
exportS.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";

NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@", @"song"];

exportS.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];;
[exportS exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if (exportS.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
    {
        //then rename mov format to the original format.
        NSFileManager *manage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *mp3Path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@.%@", @"song", @".mp3"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        [manage moveItemAtPath:path toPath:mp3Path error:&error];
    }
}];
```

Comment: hey Bilal were you able to find a solution for this? Im trying to export an mp3 file but the metadata doesnt seem to come through

Comment: @MiMo I gaveup using apple api for working with mp3 and used taglib (https://taglib.github.io) instead

Comment: I know this is old and I don't work with obj-c, but in case someone else comes here looking: From what I can see the metadata items were never copied to the export session from the original asset.